Replace single toggle switch with double switch for ceiling fan and light
I have a couple of ideas on how to fix.

Add Junction box at ceiling box to allow room for additional wiring.
Add 2 wire (black, white, ground) from power feed coming in from receptacle and run directly to the switch box. This will give me power at the switch.
Connect power to new double switch and use the existing 3 wire (black, red, white, ground) to connect to the ceiling fan/light combo.
Add new wire from junction box to bedroom switch box to bring power directly to the switch eliminating the series wire today.


Added diagram and edited for clarity 
The power source feeds the light from a receptacle, not at the switch.
I have a circuit that feeds the first receptacle in my office on 12/2 wire.
From receptacle, it feeds power to a ceiling fan with light kit currently working on single toggle and pull strings.
12/3 wire runs from the light to a single toggle switch.
Also in switch box there is 12/2 wire running in series to the switch box in my master bedroom.
When I added the double switch in the office instead of operating the light and fan in the office, it operates the light switch in our master bedroom.

The problem is not with the switch, it is with the wire ( Black or red) you have connected to the switch.  The wire does not run to the device you want it to work.  You must locate that wire.  You may need to use a service to upload pics.  ( Sorry not computer techy at all here)  If you can post the diagram please post it, it will help.

You may now have enough site reputation points to upload images in your post. If not, upload to an external image host and link it in your post. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Note the difference between wire and cable for clearer communication.

@JanetSmith please delete the comments and  edit your question instead ... comments are not the place for information ... this is not a chat forum

@RMDman added diagram and edited question for clarification. thank you

@Janet Smith,  Sorry your diagrams look more like a Football play. They mean nothing without some labeling.
